# Rails 5: how to respond_to js after redirect?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

On good old rails 4.2 I used to submit my remote: true form via ajax

```
$.ajax
   type: 'POST'
   url: post_url
   data: $("##{instance_type}-modal-form").serialize() + '&redirect_url=' + redirect_url
   dataType: 'script'
```

In my controller i was redirecting if redirect_url is present

```
if params[ :redirect_url ]
  format.html { redirect_to params[ :redirect_url ] }
  format.js { redirect_to params[ :redirect_url ] }
...
```

And I used to be redirected to new.js.coffee template. But now, on 5.0.0.1 it redirects to HTML

```
    Started PATCH "/call_journals/111" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-08-21 00:02:06 +0300
Processing by CallJournalsController#update as JS
.........

Redirected to http://localhost:3000/partners/new?call_journal_id=111
Completed 200 OK in 33ms (ActiveRecord: 3.1ms)

Started GET "/partners/new?call_journal_id=111" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-08-21 00:02:06 +0300
Processing by PartnersController#new as HTML
  Parameters: {"call_journal_id"=>"111"}
```

What do I do to get this fixed?

Answer (score 1):

**Solution**

After redirect you cannot use `format.js` for user response. Because to use `javascript` response your application needs to get ajax request or remote call without redirecting page. But you can use `json` format.